# how to add a table to sql and define it to existing table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with phpbb and I have this to go with.

add to phpbb_topics

```
Field: poll_show_votes
Type: TINYINT
Length/Values: 2
Attribute: UNSIGNED
Null: not null
Default: 0
```

Now I know how to do it in my phpmyadmin but i do not know how to convert it to a SQL query.

can someone please explain how I would do this.

Comment: did you check the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER table phpbb_topics
ADD poll_show_votes TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```